# react-select Creatable: transforming created options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I trying to use [react-select](https://react-select.com/)'s [Creatable](https://react-select.com/creatable) select component to allow users to add multiple CORS Origins to be registered for my authentication server. I would like to be able to allow users to paste full URLs, and have these URLs be transformed into Origins (format: `<protocol>://<origin>[:port]`) once they are added to the Creatable select.

As an example, the user could paste `http://some-domain.com:1234/management/clients?param1=abc&param2=123#fragment_stuff` into the Creatable select, and this whole URL would automatically be converted/added as just its origin components: `http://some-domain.com:1234`.

This is a reduced version the component I've wrote (TypeScript):

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
...


type MyOptionType = {
    label: string,
    value: string,
}

function SomeComponent(props:{}) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState<MyOptionType[]>([]);

    const onOptionsChanged = (newOptions: OptionsType<MyOptionType>) => {
        // Get only options containing valid URLs, with valid origins
        const validUrlsWithOrigins = newOptions.filter(option => {
            try {
                return !!(new URL(option.value).origin);
            } catch (error) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Transform options (e.g.: "http://some-domain.com:1234/abc?def=ghi#jkl" will become "http://some-domain.com:1234")
        const newOptionsOrigins = validUrlsWithOrigins
            .map(option => new URL(option.value).origin)
            .map(origin => ({label: origin, value: origin}));
        setOptions(newOptionsOrigins);
    }

    return <CreatableSelect isMulti options={options} onChange={onOptionsChanged} />
}
```

While debugging using React Developer Tools, I can see that the state of my component is being transformed accordingly, having only the **origin** part of my URLs being kept in the state:

[image: React Developer Tools]

The problem is that the Creatable select component is rendering the full URL instead of only the URL's Origin:

[image: Creatable select's rendered output]

Why isn't the Creatable select in sync with the component's state? Is there a way to solve this, or is it a limitation on react-select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish two things here - `options` prop of `CreatableSelect` holds an array of all the possibilites. But the value of this component is managed by `value` property.

You can check `Multi-select text input` example [on docs page](https://react-select.com/creatable) but basically you'll need to:

keep values and option separetly:

```
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState<MyOptionType[]>([]);
const [value, setValue] = React.useState<MyOptionType[]>([]);

const createOption = (label: string) => ({
  label,
  value: label
});
```

```
<CreatableSelect
      isMulti
      options={options}
      value={options}
      onChange={onOptionsChanged}
    />
```

and modify your `onOptionsChanged` function

1. set `value` of transformed and validated input
2. add new options to `options` state variable (all options, without duplicates)

Here's some example:

```
// Transform options (e.g.: "http://some-domain.com:1234/abc?def=ghi#jkl" will become "http://some-domain.com:1234")
    const newOptionsOrigins = validUrlsWithOrigins
      .map((option) => new URL(option.value).origin)
      .map((origin) => createOption(origin));

    setValue(newOptionsOrigins);

    //get all options without duplicates
    const allUniqueOptions: object = {};
    [...newOptionsOrigins, ...options].forEach((option) => {
      allUniqueOptions[option.value] = option.value;
    });
    setOptions(
      Object.keys(allUniqueOptions).map((option) => createOption(option))
    );
  };
```